# How to define protocol with generic type for NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

This is how I define it now:

```
protocol FetchedResultsControlable {
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>? { get set }
}
```

And what I need to do it to conform to that protocol like this:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Thread>?
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Task>?
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Notification>?
```

How can I achieve that?

This is how I am gonna use it. Simply need to extend other protocol:

```
protocol NotificationsViewModelable: FetchedResultsControlable {
    var notifications: [Notificationable] { get }
}
class NotificationsViewModel: NotificationsViewModelable {
    var notifications: [Notificationable] {
        return fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects ?? []
    }
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Notification>?
}
```

Comment: Thread/Notification are not subclasses of NSManagedObject, so what is `NSFetchedResultsController<Thread>` supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, they are subclasses of NSManagedObject;)

Comment: OK, but that might be a bit misleading, since both Task and Notification are already defined in the Foundation framework.

Comment: A protocol with an associated type might be what you are looking for. – But a bit more context would be helpful: How are you going to use your protocol?

Comment: @MartinR give me a minute, I will update a question. Thank you for your help.